# Cygwin Make replacing /bin with /win64 in target

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I have an odd problem running Make in Cygwin.

The makefile target is a call to an external tool that is installed on my Linux server at for example /apps/install_dir/tool_dir/bin/command.

The /apps nfs share is mapped to I drive in Windows.

But when I run make in Cygwin, it replaces the bin with win64 like this: /cygdrive/I/install_dir/tool_dir/win64/command

and therefore the command is not found.

Why does this occur and how can I fix it?

Comment: Sounds like something particular to your `Makefile`. Search it, and any included makefiles for something like "win64". This is not a Cygwin behavior.

Comment: I don't think its an issue with the makefile  To test this, I removed everything from the file and left only the following object:  maketest:  /cygdrive/I/install_dir/tool_dir/bin/command. With this, when I ran 'make maketest' at the prompt, it still replaced bin with win64.

Comment: Now I tested something else even more strange. I removed the Make from the deal and simply issued the command at the prompt. Even then the command path was replaced from bin to win64. I tried issuing the full command as well as setting PATH to the command's location and running it. Neither works. Seems like a major problem with Cygwin. I tried with both the 32 and 64-bit versions and got the same result.

Comment: I don't think so.  The behavior you're describing has nothing to do with Cygwin.  Perhaps it has something to do with your NFS client.